# How to align text in html list with custom bullets using li::before

Tags: html, css, html-lists

With a classic `<ul> <li>` list, if the text inside a `<li>` is on more that 2 lines, the texte is perfectly align . See this snippet ans screen shot (the red line show the perfect align) :

[image]

```html
<ul>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget pellentesque sem, sed condimentum orci. Sed ut justo nisl. Fusce sed justo eget nisl euismod congue in non lectus. Nulla nibh tortor, suscipit at aliquet pellentesque, varius ut mauris. Cras id ipsum eget lorem consequat lacinia. Sed aliquet aliquam feugiat.</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget pellentesque sem, sed condimentum orci. Sed ut justo nisl. Fusce sed justo eget nisl euismod congue in non lectus. Nulla nibh tortor, suscipit at aliquet pellentesque, varius ut mauris. Cras id ipsum eget lorem consequat lacinia. Sed aliquet aliquam feugiat.</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget pellentesque sem, sed condimentum orci. Sed ut justo nisl. Fusce sed justo eget nisl euismod congue in non lectus. Nulla nibh tortor, suscipit at aliquet pellentesque, varius ut mauris. Cras id ipsum eget lorem consequat lacinia. Sed aliquet aliquam feugiat.</li>

</ul>
```

Now, i had to change the bullet color so i have modified the css like this. It works but the text is not align (the 2nd line is under the custom bullet. How can i handle this and have a text align on the 1st line ?

See snippet and screen shot :

[image]

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li::before {
  content: "\002022";
  color: #d4b340;
  padding-right: 18px
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget pellentesque sem, sed condimentum orci. Sed ut justo nisl. Fusce sed justo eget nisl euismod congue in non lectus. Nulla nibh tortor, suscipit at aliquet pellentesque, varius ut mauris.
    Cras id ipsum eget lorem consequat lacinia. Sed aliquet aliquam feugiat.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget pellentesque sem, sed condimentum orci. Sed ut justo nisl. Fusce sed justo eget nisl euismod congue in non lectus. Nulla nibh tortor, suscipit at aliquet pellentesque, varius ut mauris.
    Cras id ipsum eget lorem consequat lacinia. Sed aliquet aliquam feugiat.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget pellentesque sem, sed condimentum orci. Sed ut justo nisl. Fusce sed justo eget nisl euismod congue in non lectus. Nulla nibh tortor, suscipit at aliquet pellentesque, varius ut mauris.
    Cras id ipsum eget lorem consequat lacinia. Sed aliquet aliquam feugiat.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: A user downvoted the question but he didn’t explain why. I’ve tried to explain precisely the question with code snippet. I don’t understand what is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `:before` element using absolute position

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  position:relative;
  padding-left:20px;
}
ul li::before {
  content: "\002022";
  color: #d4b340;
  padding-right: 5px;
  left:0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget pellentesque sem, sed condimentum orci. Sed ut justo nisl. Fusce sed justo eget nisl euismod congue in non lectus. Nulla nibh tortor, suscipit at aliquet pellentesque, varius ut mauris.
    Cras id ipsum eget lorem consequat lacinia. Sed aliquet aliquam feugiat.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget pellentesque sem, sed condimentum orci. Sed ut justo nisl. Fusce sed justo eget nisl euismod congue in non lectus. Nulla nibh tortor, suscipit at aliquet pellentesque, varius ut mauris.
    Cras id ipsum eget lorem consequat lacinia. Sed aliquet aliquam feugiat.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget pellentesque sem, sed condimentum orci. Sed ut justo nisl. Fusce sed justo eget nisl euismod congue in non lectus. Nulla nibh tortor, suscipit at aliquet pellentesque, varius ut mauris.
    Cras id ipsum eget lorem consequat lacinia. Sed aliquet aliquam feugiat.</li>
</ul>
```

or another way no need to add `:before` element

```css
ul li{
  color: #d4b340;
}
ul li p{
  color:#000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget pellentesque sem, sed condimentum orci. Sed ut justo nisl. Fusce sed justo eget nisl euismod congue in non lectus. Nulla nibh tortor, suscipit at aliquet pellentesque, varius ut mauris.
    Cras id ipsum eget lorem consequat lacinia. Sed aliquet aliquam feugiat.</p></li>
  <li><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget pellentesque sem, sed condimentum orci. Sed ut justo nisl. Fusce sed justo eget nisl euismod congue in non lectus. Nulla nibh tortor, suscipit at aliquet pellentesque, varius ut mauris.
    Cras id ipsum eget lorem consequat lacinia. Sed aliquet aliquam feugiat.</p></li>
  <li><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget pellentesque sem, sed condimentum orci. Sed ut justo nisl. Fusce sed justo eget nisl euismod congue in non lectus. Nulla nibh tortor, suscipit at aliquet pellentesque, varius ut mauris.
    Cras id ipsum eget lorem consequat lacinia. Sed aliquet aliquam feugiat.</p></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `text-indent`

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  text-indent: -1.5em
}

ul li::before {
  content: "\002022";
  color: #d4b340;
  padding-right: 18px
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget pellentesque sem, sed condimentum orci. Sed ut justo nisl. Fusce sed justo eget nisl euismod congue in non lectus. Nulla nibh tortor, suscipit at aliquet pellentesque, varius ut mauris.
    Cras id ipsum eget lorem consequat lacinia. Sed aliquet aliquam feugiat.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget pellentesque sem, sed condimentum orci. Sed ut justo nisl. Fusce sed justo eget nisl euismod congue in non lectus. Nulla nibh tortor, suscipit at aliquet pellentesque, varius ut mauris.
    Cras id ipsum eget lorem consequat lacinia. Sed aliquet aliquam feugiat.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget pellentesque sem, sed condimentum orci. Sed ut justo nisl. Fusce sed justo eget nisl euismod congue in non lectus. Nulla nibh tortor, suscipit at aliquet pellentesque, varius ut mauris.
    Cras id ipsum eget lorem consequat lacinia. Sed aliquet aliquam feugiat.</li>
</ul>
```